How do I get the date out of this string?
PowerShell 5.1
How do I get the date out of this string? Are those delimiters pretty good to use?
'blah blah ???5/28/24 15:55??? blah blah blah' -match '???.*\s.*???'
$Matches

I was hoping this would do it:
-match '???.*\s.*???'

if its only the date you could use (?:[0-9]{1,2}/){2}[0-9]{2}, if you want the time also need to expand it a little bit

I'm looking for everything between the ???

but is it always a date ? if so, does it always have this same format ? if you want whats in between the ??? then (?<=\?{3})[^?]+ should work too

This works, so please add answer for credit. Can you help me understand how [^?]+ delimits the ??? in the end of the string?

the [^?]+ means "match any character that is not ? 1 or more times, as many times as possible (greedy)"

The ConvertFrom-String is often forgotten for a potential solution for a question like this. Unfortunately it is difficult to give a formal answer based on your example, but the example https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string#example-4-use-an-expression-as-the-value-of-the-templatecontent-parameter-save-the-results-in-a-variable might give you idea how use this cmdlet.

You need to escape the ? as it is a special regex character (quantifier), what I imagine you wanted was \?\?\?.*\s.*\?\?\? or simplified \?{3}.*\s.*\?{3} and if you wanted to capture what is in between the ??? then you would need a capturing group, so:
'blah blah ???5/28/24 15:55??? blah blah blah' -match '\?{3}(.*\s.*)\?{3}'
$Matches[1] # => 5/28/24 15:55

See https://regex101.com/r/0DgImA/1 for regex details.
Another option that might work for your use case is using a lookbehind assertion:
'blah blah ???5/28/24 15:55??? blah blah blah' -match '(?<=\?{3})[^?]+'
$Matches[0] # => 5/28/24 15:55

See https://regex101.com/r/n7g4qP/1 for regex details.

would it be better if i use a different delimiter than the question marks, I'm in control of that part too? I just need something pretty unique I'm guessing to target what I'm looking for.

hard to tell @Rod, don't think its in me to decide that. ??? seems fine tho

thanks for that extra insight in your answer above

np! glad it helped @Rod if you have further questions feel free to ask

for the  -match statement it returns true, how would i suppress that since i'm only interested in the value. Maybe something like > null

@Rod normally you can use an if condition, if ($thing -match 'pattern') { $Matches ... but if you're 100% sure that your pattern will get a match out of your string you can simply $null = $thing -match 'pattern' or a direct .NET API call [regex]::Match($thing, 'pattern').Value

got it. btw i changed delimiter to iii 'iii5/28/24 15:56iii' -match '(?<=i{3})[^i]+'

Do you mean [regex]::Match($thing, 'pattern').Groups[1].Value?

@Rod, does this meet your need? The result is a [string] and not a [datetime] or [DateOnly] type.

@lit .Groups[1].Value would be incorrect for the lookbehind pattern as there is no capturing group 1 in it

Yes, for the lookbehind it would be $Matches[0].

@Rod, If you are in control, I would use a specific datetime format (e.g. iso 8602). Or yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss together with the word bounderies (\b) this would be pretty specific.

$BaseString = 'blah blah ???5/28/24 15:55??? blah blah blah'

# Pre-escape the delimeter, just in case
$Delimeter = [regex]::escape('?')

# Prepare the regular expression pattern
# doing this on a separate line to keep things easier to read.
$RegexPattern = ".*$Delimeter([^$Delimeter]+)$Delimeter.*"

# returns and assign only the matched group
$DateTimeString = $BaseString -replace $RegexPattern, '$1'

$DateTimeString

